# can't fetch updated packages from a local offline ubuntu repo mirror

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, repository

I am attempting to create an offline package repo for ubuntu 16.04LTS.
I have a repo served out over a small web service, and my sources.list updated to use my local copy.  my sources.list contains the following

```
deb http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/ xenial-security main universe multiverse restricted
```

I am attempting to update the locally installed version of perl for example, the currently installed version is 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 and the version in the Packages file and in the repo is 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6.
apt update successfully finds the correct Package.gz file containing this package, yet when I do an apt list --upgradeable or apt upgrade perl, I am told that the latest version is installed.
What am I missing?

After running apt update

```
Get:1 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:4 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:7 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:10 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages   
Ign:12 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en  
Ign:13 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages   
Ign:15 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en  
Get:4 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Ign:5 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages          
Get:6 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Get:7 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7,532 kB]         
Ign:8 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages            
Get:9 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en [4,354 kB]
Get:10 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Ign:11 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:12 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en [106 kB]
Get:13 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8,344 B]
Ign:14 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Get:15 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [2,908 B]
Ign:5 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages   
Ign:16 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:19 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:22 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:24 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:25 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:28 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:29 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:30 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:33 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:34 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:35 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:36 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:37 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:39 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign:8 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Err:5 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Get:16 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,019 kB]
Ign:17 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages   
Get:18 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [398 kB]
Get:19 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [763 kB]
Ign:20 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Get:21 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [319 kB]
Get:22 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.7 kB]
Ign:23 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:24 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [8,440 B]
Get:25 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,616 B]
Ign:26 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Get:27 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,272 B]
Get:28 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [732 kB]
Ign:29 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Get:30 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [287 kB]
Get:31 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [456 kB]
Ign:32 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Get:33 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [186 kB]
Get:34 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,600 B]
Ign:35 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:36 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [2,676 B]
Get:37 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [7,204 B]
Ign:38 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Get:39 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [2,152 B]
Ign:17 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:29 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:32 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:38 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Err:17 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:20 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Err:29 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:32 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:38 http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Fetched 18.6 MB in 1s (9,427 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Server logs

```
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46400 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46472 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46490 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46492 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/76858a337b1665561a256cea6f7ef32515517754e3c5e54c1895cf29e1b41884 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46496 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/1e2ad23fc1d94f6af93b2f64bfd5766cdc73efc9b6152f06471e534dae2e278f - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46500 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/f514e12580e59b8f6ae10801a91f14708bdead04db91aa20fe9e2c0384413c67 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46506 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/c8bc8c1425fef0712430d3991cf15ea96892aa5e13130b36c126fa90887ca756 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46512 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/504313460a80c8d83fe8a45d2958284e5255ba0776b3e729074c8f8a7368d191 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46516 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/18dacc7ff138747cd23eaa7a6691e259ab48c1fbc7df219cf85e5891d8c6b0f8 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46520 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/03b5a74941485533400b6103c2f2255be7620a7715b5eb5de77e26e892593d30 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46522 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/d66f0e429a38786fda01c1b8f540fb888e717b29e908096c1e40dca7316236ae - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46524 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/323f1839768b76c9184bd91f970b77a504920ea9c755925824e9e2aee705c696 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46526 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/55a464067040aa2e6237c1a7fe3dd1d06690472d211d7f0fe1697bb127404182 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46528 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/160f4e8be10c9b9071aca7f690e5837983c9186e9247ae36d671b00a530f6d83 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46530 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/02cbeba7eff7b00f22ee839e33219b7b9a2fd7ee2403e142cb4cdb93d116170b - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46532 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46536 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46538 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46540 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46560 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46562 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46584 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46586 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46588 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46590 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46592 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46594 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:50 2019] 192.168.0.11:46596 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46598 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/46029bf9571167d7191cbfeb5e9036a8e94f1103890bf659d93c0fd730b83b5a - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46616 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/96de71b07f64f9114a9c487b519d4497b501244a11be9fb0fab081e3702f3ab6 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46618 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/d4f8d1a778e5d7ddec567f75d7c4bd06178b9f3ec3bc0e5783d0133c0e932dd6 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46620 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/7fc0a2de6bd13c8f552b712fb26e23ef26520e619e6cb20b8ad7d9915506f3bb - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46622 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/cdf2df886d804fb69661e67730e17a96a3df1bf9ed73325364cdbd85932b98e2 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46624 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/f342de0122160125541b6fca331f61756b243d9aa794dfe7cc3a1bea1d49b92a - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46626 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/ee58e54cec2f7d900e4ef94bbeb9a2746a53a805261734eaa78a9e8e4252cd2a - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46628 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/48738d40ddc4f4fb5da4aa81cf261d1b7c90e65bf4a36a03c227a8b054aaa9d1 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46630 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/6947a41bae92dc9e84ef8695edee2f85b570f678a1c42eedfb5d036ac87c8d3f - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46632 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/586a059635c03a0b5423e60148d56b29259d64a38d2dfb0ed68f24365293c338 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46636 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/1e879b055774ba2ac90c9b1348796570fad81bb176016465789cd714ed29fb14 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46638 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/658d882a56cc0d38382698c5fec094f80dba40119732d0b52c8e9af1d5db3aea - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46640 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/990e73ba455a10325bd2e92fb470cd0d5968740368869ffb082f9b8169dc9867 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46642 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/00857f74c8a32c2acdc55714388e7dcc66397107085ce0bb5589b6a0e2b6e2b7 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46644 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/00c5ed23413f0fa6cc93a09b77c3451b4fb794d9c4eaf3aa72a5a9ce2892afe3 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46646 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/6e81fd050638cbde1d1350523ad5f5c12498706f287f45c7e869424c5cb471bc - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46648 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/3a3ad0274dcc6897a4cb95cdbbab01354199a718263c691fab3dbc8134603ffc - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46650 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/e294059bccc165671f59c577f09a78a0da51f386da16998c5fdcdb4322da38cf - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46652 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/d417b2e45828b5e52e5573016f070519a4a3e3eeac9bf1224024e5a24d3715a6 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46654 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/529bc4182035c0eb42fc26a14ba3a5beda9b77fadbf9fc1cf07d25d87f0982c3 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46656 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/0d3e447048c15cc8d231c4443214565e32c6d33550faeff0a1337bbf4b218f06 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46658 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/f1b4442b9dda392337d90c3ceeb33ce46339629547a8725f425e309d51edce49 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46660 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/9331633e0354a4d75b639d0dc1f69d79ad22075fc14f99ba5ccff49bb4f9939d - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46662 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/123a306d97d3144c2951938b2728e9331cbe4157e9335b88f95c39ab87568899 - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46664 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46666 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46668 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46670 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46672 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46674 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46676 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46678 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46696 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46698 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46702 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46704 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46706 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46708 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46710 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46712 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46714 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46716 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46718 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46720 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46740 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46742 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46744 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46746 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46750 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46752 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46754 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.xz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46756 [200]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.xz
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46758 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46760 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46762 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46764 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46766 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46768 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46770 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46772 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46774 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46776 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46778 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46780 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46782 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46784 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46786 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 13:59:51 2019] 192.168.0.11:46788 [404]: /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages - No such file or directory
```

Packages file for perl lists the following;

```
Package: perl
Architecture: amd64
Version: 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6
Multi-Arch: allowed
```

apt upgrade perl on the client yields

```
perl is already the newest version (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5).
```

Comment: which Software do you use? i use apt-cacher-ng for this

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what software was used to make the repo.  It looks like it was made and used successfully in the past, not l just not on this system before.  There has to be some log somewhere or something simple I'm missing because everything looks right except it doesn't work

Comment: and whats the error?

Comment: Apt upgrade perl says it's at the latest version, when there is a newer version in the repo and called out in the packages fine hosted on the repo

Comment: did you run apt Update?

Comment: several times.....

Comment: then post the complete output of your commands that we can see what happening and also the same for the webserver logs

Comment: please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

the culprit is that attempts to index packages for 386 fails.  It is not clear that this aborts the entire indexing process, which it now seems to do.  Adding [ arch=amd64 ] in sources.list to the deb lines results in an apt update that succeeds 100% and after which updateable packages are listed

Comment: this is what i would tell you, your mirror has no Support for i386 and thats why i asked all tze time for the log output 

Comment: I added the output.  But it wasn't clear to me that indexing of the separate Package files would depend on successful fetching of all indexes from a given repo, since apt said that some indexes had succeeded.

Comment: this is why i use apt-cacher-ng so i dont need to care about it